# I need to authenticate a user directly in the console under Devise. How can I do it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I need to do something like this from Rails console to do some testing and experiments:

> User.authenticate(username, password)

I'm using Devise, but I have no idea how to do this.

I saw this other answer here

[How to sign in a user using Devise from a Rails console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929078/how-to-sign-in-a-user-using-devise-from-a-rails-console)

But I need something cleaner and more direct. If necessary, I just need the algorithm to hash an attempted password with the salt and compare it to the encryped_password.

Is it this?

```
User.find(1).valid_password?('password123')
```

Comment: How do you authenticate users in your sessions_controller create method? (or whatever controller and action users hit to sign in)

Comment: I replaced warden.authenicate! with my own code that uses the User.find_by_username( ).valid_password?() method.

Comment: It's crazy how many layers of indirection there is in Devise for stuff that used to be pretty clear and simple.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

#### General info:

Check out the [Devise README found here.](http://devise.plataformatec.com.br/)

As an example, here is a helper method that you can use to do this test:

```
class User
    def self.authenticate(username, password)
        user = User.find_for_authentication(:username => username)
        user.valid_password?(password) ? user : nil
    end
end
```

---

Testing it, I get:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > user = User.find(1)
    User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
    User id: 1, {...USER DETAILS SHOWN HERE...}
1.9.3p194 :002 > user.valid_password?('is this it?')=> false
```

---

Also working: `User.find(1).valid_password?('1')` in Rails console:

```
1.9.3p194 :011 > User.find(1).valid_password?('1')
    User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
    => false
```

---

For reference, here's my Devise setup for the User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base`

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :timeoutable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  {...}

end
```

---

Like you said in the comments, there is no `sessions_controller` since Devise. Look into the Devise config file in `/config/initializers/devise.rb`. Depending on your application configuration, you may also want to look at the `token.rb` and `session_store.rb` initializer configs.

**EDIT:** Can you check your user model to see if devise is properly configured for it? Compare it against my `devise` line. The `:validatable` property could be missing.

**EDIT 2:** Added the helper method to do this test if you want to do it outside of the console. Check up top.

Side-note: The [`rails_admin` gem](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki) is pretty useful and may be worth checking out!

Hope that helps.

Comment: One caveat I would give on this answer - it seems to bypass 'paranoid' mode, if you've enabled that in the devise config. I've not yet been able to find a better way to do it, though.

Comment: I appreciate that, just thought I'd add the comment so that future readers are aware :-) For what it's worth, everything here is still accurate!

Comment: Awesome, thank you for confirming that @DaveMongoose I wasnt sure, I've been out of the RoR loop for a while now.

Answer (score 5):

I think implement can be much simpler without using any kind of gem. 
At least we know the email id.

email :  'currentuser@email.com' 
Current password: 'rubyuser'

```
user = User.find_by_email('currentuser@email.com')

user.valid_password?('wrong_password')  #returns false
user.valid_password?('rubyuser')    #returns true
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this method is simpler. It looks the same as what I posted above except not wrapped in a helper. Also, how is this "without using any kind of gem"? You're also using Devise (right?), which is the only gem we're all talking about. Haha, I realize its been quite a while since these were posted (plus I haven't looked at rails in some time) so I appreciate any clarification. Thanks!

Comment: Also works for Sorcery (hope this helps searchers find this faster than I did).