# Rails 3 - How can you get access to Devise's current_user in the IRB console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session, devise, irb

I'm doing some design/debugging in IRB and need to login a user and then be able to use current_user in my efforts.

From Brian Deterling's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929078/how-to-sign-in-a-user-using-devise-from-a-rails-console) to another question, I have been able to successfully login and access a page response with this sequence:

```
>> ApplicationController.allow_forgery_protection = false
>> app.post('/sign_in', {"user"=>{"login"=>"some-login-id", "password"=>"some-password"}})
>> app.get '/some_other_path_that_only_works_if_logged_in'
>> pp app.response.body
```

NOTE: If you get a 200 response you are not logged in.  You need a 302 redirect to indicate a successful login.  See Tim Santeford's answer.

I've been able to get session info:

```
1.9.3-p125 :009 > app.session
 => {"_csrf_token"=>"1yAn0jI4VWzUH84PNTH0lVhjpY98e9echQGS4=", "session_id"=>"89984667d30d0fec71f2a5cbb9017e24"}
```

I've tried everything I can think of to try to get to `current_user` via `app` and `app.session`, but no luck.  How can I get `current_user`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`current_user` is a property of the controller so after `app.post('/sign_in', ...` you can call `app.controller.current_user` in your rails console to get the User object

Comment: I tried it and current_user is nil.  When I do the login procedure described in the question, I get a 200 response and app.session returns the csrf_token, so I know I'm logged in OK.  app.controller responds with pages and pages of data.  But app.controller.current_user returns nil.  I'm using Devise - are you?

Comment: Looks like some mass assignment issue on app.post was causing my login to be unsuccessful (a 200 response is not a successful post in this case - very confusing.)  Once I got a 302 response, then app.controller.current_user works.  I would not have figured out the login issue without Tim Santeford's answer.

Comment: I guess it's because the 200 means the app renders the sign in form succesfully (along the flash message saying you cannot be identified).

Answer (score 4):

It might be possible that you are not really logging in. One thing to keep in mind is that Devise I build on top of Warden which is rack middleware.

I tried your app.post method of logging in on an app I'm working on that uses Devise. After posting to the login page and getting a 302 redirect the `app.session` showed the warden user id.

```
>> app.session
{
 "_csrf_token"=>"dT0/BqgLb84bnE+f1g...",
 "warden.user.user.key"=>["User", [42843], "$2a$10$1OU.1BixIba..."],
 "session_id"=>"0dd49c05ff4e6362c207c6eb877f86cd"
}
```

I was able to fetch the user like this:

```
>> current_user = User.find(app.session["warden.user.user.key"][1][0])
```

When I logged out and then tried logging in with a bad password I get a 200 and then the app.session is missing the warden user info and only contained the csrf token and session id like your example.

BTW: Once logged in `app.controller.current_user` was nil even when the warden user id was in the session.

Comment: Tim - Thanks for pointing out the 200 vs 320 issue.  I decided to choose Suguha's answer because of its simplicity, although I tested yours and it works also.  Sorry I can't choose both.

Comment: No problem. I didn't know you could login using the app object like this prior to your question so I learn something by answering.