# Call controller from rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http

I would like to call controller action from rake task. My question is what method is the best to prepare http request? Thanks for all tips.

Edit:
Have someone another tip? I tried this and not work:

```
controller_obj = Controller.new
controller.your_method
```

I got this exception:

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Controller
```

Edit2:
I tried:

```
sess = ActionController::Integration::Session.new
sess.post('/route', 'codes=3')
```

But I got (I have require 'action_controller/integration' in rake file) :

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- action_controller/integration
```

Comment: what do you want to do? the controller should handle requests, your task is not a real request, it looks like you need something else but it's not clear because you didn't say what you really want to do

Comment: Temporary I need to call this controller from rake task. So I need simulate http request. And how to simulate POST request? Or GET with params

Comment: that's "HOW" you want to do it, but what do you want? why do you need to simulate a post or get request? maybe you need something else, it's not normal to call a controller action inside a task

Comment: It is simple. I have to add Products data and I want to send to controller some parameters and next create entity in DB. In the nearest future I will create view with some form and I will use this controller. But now I would like to send some data from rake task to controller and add entity to DB. It is no matter how but I would to have this data in my controller.

Comment: you can't do that, you have to move the logic to a model and maybe some logic in the task and your controller and your taks will have a similar (but different) code, your are trying to use a controller for something that it's not for

Answer (score 13):

```
task :use_controller_method_in_rake => :environment do
  session = ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(Rails.application)
  session.get "/foo"
  session.post "/bar", {my_post_params: 'foobar'}
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that! And BTW, please note that now the recommended way of getting such session is http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/Runner.html#method-i-open_session, although I wasn't able to make it work in the 5 minutes I dedicated for it. So your method is still better.

Comment: If you're using devise, you'll need to sign in first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929078/how-to-sign-in-a-user-using-devise-from-a-rails-console

Answer (score 9):

You should move that action's behavior to a model class, then use that action with the instance of that model class. This is the standard approach.

**move** `controller/action` to a `model class` (**Recommended**).
In your rake task, do the following....

```
model_obj = Model.new
model_obj.your_instance_method
```

And **still** you **want** to call controller action then you should create an instance of your controller in your rake task and call that action with that instance(if that method is an instance method.)

```
controller_obj = Controller.new
controller.your_method
```

Comment: It is temporary solution. In the nearest future I will create view for this case, but now I would like to prepare controller.
controller_obj = Controller.new <- I don't know that It will work because I have to call controller using http request (I thing maybe I'm wrong)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @chris-finne, that was very helpful. Note that session.response.body is where
you can access the results. Here's an method I'm using in a rake task:

```rb
def api_json_get(url, params={})
  @rails_session ||= ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(Rails.application)
  @rails_session.get(url, { :format => :json }.merge(params))
  JSON.parse(@rails_session.response.body)
end
```

Notice I'm memoizing the session object since it's quite slow to instantiate and I'm calling this method many times.