# Can we call a controller method inside rake tasks...?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there any way by which controller methods can be used inside Rake task.

Comment: Did you try typing your question into google? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22936245/call-controller-from-rake-task

Answer (score 1):

You can always call your endpoint but my guess is that you need some logic that lives inside your controller. The best approach would be to extract that logic into some service and use that service in both the controller and your rake task. You get the bonus of being able to test it more easily.