# Make request from rails console return 302

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-console

In Rails 4.0.3, I try to send a http get request from rails console:

```
app.get '/'
```

it returns with response code 302 redirected.

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-03 11:57:11 +0200
=> 302
```

However, this page is a public page, shouldn't be redirected.

#### Any clue how can I make it working?

Comment: in `rails 4.1.5` returns `200`

Comment: what routes have you set for `root`?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but that's because my app need to login as the first, so I do the following command:

```
>> ApplicationController.allow_forgery_protection = false
>> app.post '/users/sign_in', :user => {:email => "user@example.com", :password => "12345"}
```

these commands will return 302, you can now go to the root path as the following:

```
>> app.get '/'
```

this'll return `Completed 200 OK`, this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929078/how-to-sign-in-a-user-using-devise-from-a-rails-console) may help you.

Comment: Hi Mohamed, I tried your solution, it does not work. As I said, the home page is a public page, it does not require login.

Answer (score 0):

I finnally found the problem. It is caused by a Rails middleware gem I used to check UserAgent called [browser](https://github.com/fnando/browser).

I have the following code to only allow "modern browsers" to access my site

```
Rails.configuration.middleware.use Browser::Middleware do
next if (browser.bot? or browser.search_engine?) 
redirect_to upgrade_path unless browser.modern?
end
```

As rails console has no UserAgent setting, it always redirects to /upgrade.

I update the code to:

```
Rails.configuration.middleware.use Browser::Middleware do
next if (browser.bot? or browser.search_engine? or (Rails.env == 'test') or (Rails.env == 'development') )
redirect_to upgrade_path unless browser.modern?
end
```

Now it works!