# How can I sign out a devise user from the Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, logout

My devise users are "database_authenticatable" and "token_authenticatable". I've tried deleting the "authentication_token" field in the database for that user from the console, but they still seem to be able to use their existing auth token. Deleting the user entirely works, but I don't want to go that far.

Edit: for clarity. I want to use the rails **console** to sign out a user. i.e. run `rails console` and then some command.

Answer (score 20):

Devise provides helper methods to do these things:

```
user = User.find(params[:id])
sign_in user
sign_out user
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Since I'm using the *console*, I don't have those methods. When I run the sign_in command I get ```NoMethodError: undefined method `sign_in' for main:Object```

Comment: From console you can try this: `>> ApplicationController.allow_forgery_protection = false` `>> app.post('/users/sign_in', {"user"=>{"email"=>"login@example.com", "password"=>"password"}})`

Comment: Best thing would be to use pry gem. Once you install it, just add the line pry to your controller and you can access sign_out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Devise you could use the below in your **rails console**. This works perfect for me as in my app if you are using only 1 session per user account. I am storing my sessions in redisDB.

```
user = User.first
user.update_attributes(unique_session_id: "")
```

All I had to do was clear my users unique_session_id for that user and rails kicks the user out of the session.

But for multiple sessions for the same User account this does not work.

If you want to clear all user sessions you can do the below from terminal

```
rake db:sessions:clear
```

Comment: It gives ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'unique_session_id' for User.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find way you make user log out from Rails console. but If you use Redis as cache storage, you can run this command in Terminal.

**Don't do this on the production. It will clear all users's session data.**

```
redis-cli KEYS "2::*" | xargs redis-cli DEL
```

Rails store user's session as hashed value.
`2::00041b7a39e202c8210ad075ca94b1c6d5a658c455e6e9ce5ab0f789d2f9e403`
some thing like this.

Above command will delete all user's session data.

Answer (score -1):

To sign_in by Devise check this way in console:

```
$ rails console
include Warden::Test::Helpers
def sign_in(resource_or_scope, resource = nil)
  resource ||= resource_or_scope
  scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
  login_as(resource, scope: scope)
end

def sign_out(resource_or_scope)
  scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
  logout(scope)
end

@user = User.find(1)
sign_in @user
```

Then open `http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/sign_in` to test, in my case it will bypass this page and go to home page! Same to `sign_out`!

Answer (score -2):

You may be able to use the helpers that others have mentioned after including the necessary module:

`include Devise::Controllers::SignInOut`

source: [Module: Devise::Controllers::SignInOut](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/SignInOut)

There's also another SO question where someone shares a method that doesn't involve using Devise helpers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929078/how-to-sign-in-a-user-using-devise-from-a-rails-console).

Comment: I get ```NameError: uninitialized constant Devise::Controllers::SignInOut```

Comment: I'm guessing the library needs to be required first. Can you try `require 'devise'` and then the `include`? Not sure about the right filename to require so I'll keep poking around

Comment: Also edited my answer to include a link to a similar SO question with an answer marked correct. It's for signing in rather than out but should be a similar process if you want to try that way (it's making a post to the `/signout` path with information about your user as parameters)

Comment: I get `NameError: undefined local variable or method `warden' for main:Object` at my pry console

Answer (score -3):

I'm not a fan of the `sign_out @user` pattern because, at least for the devise version I'm using, that signs out the current user, regardless of the argument I pass it. If you're storing sessions in your database then you can do this:

```
@user.update_attributes(current_sign_in_token: "")
```

TBH I don't think that's the best way to do it, but it's the best way I've seen in my own research.

Answer (score -3):

I believe you can simply update the password_salt and it will invalidate the user session on their next request.

```
user = User.first
user.update_column(:password_salt, 'reset')
```

Reference:
http://www.jonathanleighton.com/articles/2013/revocable-sessions-with-devise/

Answer (score -8):

You can create a logout link in views->layouts->application.html.erb as:-

```
<= link_to 'Log Out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

It worked for me - hope it does for others as well.

Comment: the question is to log out from console

Comment: This only works in a rails view, not in rails console.