# Rails sign-out user Devise from rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Is there a way to sign-out devise user using local `rails c` ? I was trying to use `user.update_attributes(unique_session_id: "")` or `rake db:sessions:clear` but without success

Comment: This may be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28935054/how-can-i-sign-out-a-devise-user-from-the-rails-console

Comment: @TomerShemesh I saw this and none of this method works. For sign_out user` I'm getting `NoMethodError (undefined method sign_out' for main:Object)`

Comment: I miss post the answer in wrong place. So check it, sorry for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67639213/2311619

Comment: are you storing user session in cookies or server-side?