# Cannot sign into Devise from the rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to sign into a rails app from the rails console. But I get an error message.

I do

```
app.post '/users/sign_in', :user => {:email => 'user@example.com, password: ""}
```

I get:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `main_app' for #< <Class:0x007fce257ea680>:0x007fce1dadc760>:
  /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/controllers/url_helpers.rb:65:in `_devise_route_context'
  /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/controllers/url_helpers.rb:51:in `session_path'
  app/views/users/sessions/_session_form.haml:1:in `_app_views_users_session
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This answer solved my issue. (The answer highlighted as correct did not work for me)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30351177/314721